# Any other way for signing blackberry application

Tags: blackberry

I want to sign my blackberry application but the blackberry signing server is unavailable. I am really frustrated now with this problem. Can any one tell me if there can be any work around for signing the app so that i will not have to depend on the blackberry signing server.

Comment: Today i am facing same probleam, i think Signing servers  are under maintenance

Answer (score 1):

Signing servers sometimes are under maintenance and are unavailable. Do not need to be frustrated, just wait until servers become available.

Comment: I think it goes under maintenance every day and specially when i have to sign the app. Its really ridiculous.

Comment: what can I say :) Consider development for Android and iPhone devices :)

Comment: The servers are reportedly back up now, but running slower than usual. Previously on twitter: We are experiencing issues with the Code Signing Servers and are working to restore service.  Apologies for the impact on your dev. ^MS